# Recaptcha is ignored by ajax action

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, recaptcha

I'm using Primefaces, however I can't use their p:captcha component, because it can't be rendered/updated by Ajax.
So, I'm trying to use reCaptcha's Ajax Api to create it on the form dynamically, by using Recaptcha.create. Here's the code:

```
Recaptcha.create(/*public_code*/,
                        'captchadiv', {
                            tabindex : 1,
                            theme : "red",
                            callback : Recaptcha.focus_response_field
                        });
```

Captcha has been created, but it doesn't validate actions from ajax buttons, like p:commandButton. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Primefaces, however I can't use their p:captcha component, because it can't be rendered/updated by Ajax.

False. The `p:captcha` element has an `id` attribute so it **can** be updated using AJAX. It also has a `rendered` attribute which can be set to `true` or `false`, yes even at runtime.

> Captcha has been created, but it doesn't validate actions from ajax buttons, like p:commandButton. What am I doing wrong?

I'm guessing the captcha element you're rendering has no integration with JSF/PrimeFaces. ;-)

Why not use the PrimeFaces captcha element like this:

```
<div id="captchaWrapper">
    <p:captcha rendered="captchaBean.rendered"/>
</div>
<p:commandButton value="render" action="#{captchaBean.render}" 
    update="captchaWrapper"/>
```

And have a backing bean like this:

```
public class CaptchaBean
{
    //Getter/setter omitted
    private boolean rendered;

    public void render()
    {
        rendered = true;
    }
}
```